# How to make this table don't be break by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, printing

I use jQuery to print a datatable, it displays like below. how I can make the table display complete?

[image]

this is my print jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Print_This").live("click", function () {
        //            $("#SCROLLBAR").printArea();
        var content = $("#SCROLLBAR").html();
        var docprint = window.open("SingTao", "ContentAssignment", "");
        docprint.document.open();
        docprint.document.write(content);
        docprint.document.close();
        docprint.print();
        docprint.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simply printing contents I will suggest you to put necessary CSS too to the newer opened window. Here you are calling `.print()` on `window` object. So its not at all related to `jQuery`. Please have a look at below code. Refer it and modify your above code accordingly and see what you get printed:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Print_This").live("click", function () {
        var content = $("#SCROLLBAR").html();
        var docprint = window.open("SingTao", "ContentAssignment", "");
        docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        docprint.document.write('<style type="text/css" media="print,screen">.someClass{border: 1px solid black}</style>');   //write all required css classes here OR put the link to CSS file as following line
        docprint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://some.domain.com/somefolder/somestyle.css" type="text/css" />');    //CSS present on some domain    
        docprint.document.write('</head><body>');
        docprint.document.write(content); //your contents goes here                
        docprint.document.write('</body></html>'); 
        docprint.document.close();
        docprint.print();
    });
});
```

In above code you can see; `CSS` can be added by 2 ways, either you can write `<style>` tag Or you can go for `<link>` tag to refer `.css` file present on some domain/server. Please try it and let me know what you see.

Comment: the 'content' is a table which has many rows and every row has different height. If one row can't display in a page completely, it divided into two parts ,like in that picture. So, I want control this table's pagination.

Comment: At the time of printing user may select smaller page than default one. So again taller rows will get spread over more than one page. This you can't control by code because we can simply call `print()`; after that we don't have any control over printing mechanism.